# How do I change the name of an image if it is used in another form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to make an inventory system where you can see an image of each item. To edit the image, I'm trying to replace the existing image with a different one. However, when I try to do this, I get an exception.

oldImage is the file path of the old image, new image is the file path of the new image

```
FileInfo oldImage = new FileInfo(oldImage);

// Should replace it with new image
oldImage.Replace(newImage, null);
```

Exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.FileSystem.ReplaceFile(String sourceFullPath, String destFullPath, String destBackupFullPath, Boolean ignoreMetadataErrors)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.Replace(String destinationFileName, String destinationBackupFileName, Boolean ignoreMetadataErrors)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.Replace(String destinationFileName, String destinationBackupFileName)
   at NEA_Prototype_6.EditInventoryForm.ReplaceFile() in D:\NEA\Code\NEA_Prototype_6\EditInventoryForm.cs:line 77
   at NEA_Prototype_6.EditInventoryForm.btnConfirmEdit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\NEA\Code\NEA_Prototype_6\EditInventoryForm.cs:line 58
```

I understand that the file is locked because it is being used by another process, but I don't understand what process that is. The only time that the image is used is on a separate form that isn't open. Is it just as soon as the program is run you every file used gets locked?

Comment: You have probably used `Image.FromFile()` to load the Image. Get the bytes instead, as, e.g., `var image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes([PATH])), true, false);`

Comment: "The only time that the image is used is on a separate form that isn't open." But have you disposed that form and with that every resource used on it?